# How could an amorphous species work?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, species

In the setting I'm building, then there are two lifeforms to have existed; Angel and Demons. Both are closely related, as speciation between happened rather recently in their history. They both also have very different forms to other animal species; they have physical bodies, but they're amorphous in the same sense that fog is amorphous. They're actually meant to look a bit like fog themselves; the angels White fog, and Demons black fog.

Some things that they're expected to do is to fight, though how does one fog cloud fight another fog cloud? They also had spliced their DNA with Humanity's ancient evolutionary ancestors, resulting in the Nephilim and Cambions, who were able to revolt and kill off their creators.

Comment: *how does one fog cloud fight another fog cloud?* You would need to provide some practical details about exactly how they are constructed ?  How do you damage something is directly related to how it is physically constructed and organized.   "A fog" is not much of a description in this sense.

Comment: make one have some heavily acidic property and another able to generate lightning, the evilnaughtyacidy ones then are at a significant disadvantage in an 'open battle' cause they can be hurt from a distance by uh, White Fog. This explains why the demon's are behavioraly skulky and (almost) literally backstabbing barstools.

Comment: So from playing with ideas like this, you need two things:  1) Decide how much metaphysics you will permit, because amorphous brains aren't very good at keeping structures.  The less metaphysics you want, the harder it will be. 2) Decide how wide your concept of "lifeform" is.  Quite often the only possible solutions in situations like these really stretch and make you think "could that *really* qualify as a lifeform?"

Comment: As a bare minimum, I would recommend being comfortable with treating an entire ant colony (queen, workers, soldiers and all) as a single organism.  Once you can think of an ant colony as an organism, it's a bit easier to see how exotics like fog might start to work.

Comment: E.E. Doc Smith's Palainians (and Eich, and Onlonians) are amorphous in that their appearance is constantly changing to 3-dimensional viewers. They have part of their metabolism in a 4th dimension (not time), so we're not seeing the whole story. A brilliant little handwave.

Comment: VTC OT:POB.  Please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problem with questions like this is they are broad, not objective and you've provided no criteria for judging a best answer (POB).